# Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.* MVC 5 Not registering Handler

Tags: github, asp.net-mvc-5, webhooks

I have implemented [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/09/04/introducing-microsoft-asp-net-webhooks-preview.aspx). With MVC 5. I added the package from nuget: Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Recievers.GitHub and created a WebApiConfig.cs class in App_Start folder. When sending from GitHub I am getting a status 200 ok message so the routing is working fine and response.

I then created a webhook handler to process requests, here is the code.

```
{
public class GitHubHandler : WebHookHandler
{
    public GitHubHandler()
    {
        this.Receiver = "github";
    }

    public override Task ExecuteAsync(string receiver, WebHookHandlerContext context)
    {
        string action = context.Actions.First();
        JObject data = context.GetDataOrDefault<JObject>();

        Debug.WriteLine("Made it to reciever");

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

}

And I have been unable to hit a debug point here or write to dubug console.

I am wondering if my application is not auto-registering it? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial actually works great. This is a non-issue. After a deeper dive into the code from the Microsoft.AspNet.Webhooks.Reciever.GitHub I found this:

```
            // If this is a ping request then just return. Otherwise call handlers.
        if (string.Equals(actions.FirstOrDefault(), PingEvent, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return request.CreateResponse();
        }
```

And, I then realized that the GitHub test deliver message was only sending a "ping" event, and this code says it all.

After making a commit, and generating a real event my handler is reached as expected.